# Generating dynamic table in Javascript with JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to make a Javascript table which is built with JSON. This JSON is sent from the backend ( using Django ) so it can be changed anytime.
Name of the column would be the category. My JSON form looks like:

```
var data = [
{
    "title": "Leadership",
    "category": "humaninteraction"
},
{
    "title": "Maintenance procedures",
    "category": "procedures"
},
{
    "title": "Situational Awareness",
    "category": "environmentsituations"
},
{
    "title": "Self-Criticism",
    "category": "self"
},
{
    "title": "Tools",
    "category": "aircraft"
}];
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried till now

Comment: Try [jQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) or [Dhtmlx](http://dhtmlx.com) If you are looking for a framework, else you can iterate and build something on your own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.getJSON()` to get that `JSON` from the backend and use `$.each()` to build each row. Like this:

```
function generateTable(){    
    var rows = '';
    $.getJSON( "backend/method", function( data ) {
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        rows += '<tr>';
        rows += '<td>' + data.title + '</td>';
        rows += '<td>' + data.category+ '</td>';
        rows += '</tr>';
      });
    });
    $('#tableId').append(rows);
}
```